# Help recognizing this logger

Tags: java, logging

guys I'm trying to correct an application... where I found this lines of code:

```
private static final Log log=LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class);
```

then this logger is used like this:

```
log.info("The message has the following arguments {0},{1},{2}",arg1.toString(),arg2.toString(),arg3.toString());
```

Of course this is giving me compile errors. The problem is that they have a similar pattern in several classes, where there is the same error.

The imports of the log classes are:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
```

Are these ones correct??, or I should use another imports like, Log4j or Slf4j.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It looks like the logging methods are able to accept varargs.  As you noted below, the apache commons logging classes don't take varargs.  If you find one that does, you can probably import those and have it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT : I think the specific syntax you are referring to is falling on SLF4J lines.
check the example in http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/Logger.html. Then the imports will change accordingly.

They are correct.
Refer http://commons.apache.org/logging/guide.html

If you are on maven.

use this to resolve your compilation errors

```
<!-- Apache commons-logging --> 
    <dependency> 
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId> 
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId> 
     <version>1.1.1</version> 
   </dependency>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks... however the signature of the apache commons log.info methods is:

log.info(Object message, Throwable t);

And in the project they are using:

log.info("The message has the following arguments {0},{1},{2}",arg1.toString(),arg2.toString(),arg3.toString());

This is giving me a compile error, that's says a throwable object was expected in the signature. Thanks a lot.

Comment: SLF4j includes implementations of common logging classes.  This appears to be an example of Apache Commons Logging over SLF4j.